# Setting a label on Gcloud using API and Python

Tags: python, api, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to add a new label using the API and Python. I have the following code and i keep getting errors no matter how i change it.

I used the guide here:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/setLabels

```
instances_list=list_instances(compute, "terraform-313709", "europe-west3-a")
#Getting the current labelFingerprint
labelFingerprint_value=instances_list[0]['labelFingerprint']

#Setting the labels
instances_set_labels_request_body = {
"labels": {
    "key": "value"
},
"LabelFingerprint": labelFingerprint_value
}
request = service.instances().setLabels(project="terraform-313709", zone="europe-west3-a", instance="terraform-instance", body=instances_set_labels_request_body)
print(request)
response = request.execute()
```

The full error i am getting is:

> ```
> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 412 when requesting https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/terraform-313709/zones/europe-west3-a/instances/terraform-instance/setLabels?alt=json
> ```
>
> returned "Labels fingerprint either
> invalid or resource labels have changed". Details: "[{'message': 'Labels fingerprint either invalid or resource labels have changed',
> 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'conditionNotMet', 'location':
> 'If-Match', 'locationType': 'header'}]">

What am i doing wrong here?

Thank you

Comment: The label fingerprint that you are specifying does not match the stored label fingerprint value. Is `instances_list[0]` the same instance as `terraform-instance`? My guess is that you are using the label fingerprint from a different instance.

Comment: Hi, the fingerprint is the same. I only have one instance and i also tried to hardcode it. Both cases resulted in the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it states in the error message, the fingerprint doesn't match, so it cannot update the labels, which is exactly why fingerprint is being used in the first place - to make sure you are updating what you think you are updating. I agree with John, that it is very likely that the instance you are updating is not the same as the one you grabbed the fingerprint from. Try to print out instance_list[0] and see if the 'name' matches 'terraform-instance'.

I tried with this little code (it updates all the if their name starts with 'gke' to have the label 'goog-gke-node') and it seems everything works pretty well:

```
from pprint import pprint
from time import sleep

from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()

compute = discovery.build('compute', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
project = '<PROJECT_ID>'
zone = '<INSTANCE_ZONE>'

def get_instances():
    instances = []

    request = compute.instances().list(project=project, zone=zone)
    while request is not None:
        response = request.execute()

        for instance in response['items']:
          instances.append({'name': instance.get('name'),
                            'labels': instance.get('labels', {}),
                            'labelFingerprint': instance.get('labelFingerprint')})

        request = compute.instances().list_next(previous_request=request,
                                                previous_response=response)
    return instances

def set_labels(instances, new_labels={}):
    for instance in instances:
        if instance['name'].startswith('gke'):
            instance['labels'].update(new_labels)

            instances_set_labels_request_body = {
                'labels': instance['labels'],
                'labelFingerprint': instance['labelFingerprint']
            }
            request = compute.instances().setLabels(project=project,
                                                    zone=zone,
                                                    instance=instance['name'],
                                                    body=instances_set_labels_request_body)
            response = request.execute()

# get instances before changes
instances = get_instances()
pprint(instances)

set_labels(instances, {'goog-gke-node': ''})

sleep(10) # just to make sure the labels are updates,
          # terrible, but gets the job done for this example code
          # TODO: needs more elegant solution

# get instances after changes
instances = get_instances()
pprint(instances)
```

this produces the output of:

```
[{'labelFingerprint': '22Wm4pB8r1M=',
  'labels': {},
  'name': 'gke-cluster-1-default-pool-112c2c29b29-m2hn'},
 {'labelFingerprint': '22Wm4pB8r1M=',
  'labels': {},
  'name': 'gke-cluster-1-default-pool-112c2c29b29-tpdm'},
 {'labelFingerprint': '22Wm4pB8r1M=',
  'labels': {},
  'name': 'gke-cluster-1-default-pool-112c2c29b29-xc2n'}]

[{'labelFingerprint': '3ixRn02sGuM=',
  'labels': {'goog-gke-node': ''},
  'name': 'gke-cluster-1-default-pool-112c2c29b29-m2hn'},
 {'labelFingerprint': '3ixRn02sGuM=',
  'labels': {'goog-gke-node': ''},
  'name': 'gke-cluster-1-default-pool-112c2c29b29-tpdm'},
 {'labelFingerprint': '3ixRn02sGuM=',
  'labels': {'goog-gke-node': ''},
  'name': 'gke-cluster-1-default-pool-112c2c29b29-xc2n'}]
```